# Replace Menu View Programmatically in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the example from AppCoda to create a slide-out sidebar menu. Here is the link.

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

What I am trying to do is replace the menu with a different menu on the mainViewController. And I want to do this programmatically. I already know how to do this directly from the storyboard.

Whenever I try this method, it replaces the entire view with the menu controller. I just want it to change the menu on the left sidebar.

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu_logged_in"];
UIViewController * vcl = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu_register"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there anyway to call the sidebar on the left menu and replace it with another menu. My knowledge in the iOS environment is very limited and I'm super confused on how to change this menu with a different menu.

Comment: what do you want? You want to replace menu?

Comment: Yeah. But I got it. Ill post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was instantiated the viewController from the storyboard and then called it using the setRearViewController function and then set the new menu to that.

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu_subscriber"];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
[navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];

[self.revealViewController setRearViewController:navController];
```